# Missing EXM web connection string after installation

Tags: xdb, exm

During the installation of EXM on Sitecore 8.2 Update7 I started receiving the following error. Any Clues for this exception I am not able to login to CMS

> No connection string configuration was found by the name 'exm.web'.
>
> Exception Details: Sitecore.Exceptions.ConfigurationException: No
> connection string configuration was found by the name 'exm.web'.
>
> [ConfigurationException: No connection string configuration was found
> by the name 'exm.web'.]
>
> Sitecore.ExM.Framework.DataProviders.SqlSessionDataProvider..ctor(String
> connectionStringName, String tableName) +234

Answer (score 2):

I guess you didn't add the 2 connections string (exm.master and exm.web) which are mandatory to add :

[image]

Please check the installation guide at: https://dev.sitecore.net/~/media/C511623DBB4B451DBCAC0DAC64C9A59C.ashx

Comment: Connecting string need to be added  after installing of EXm package but I am getting this error during installation itself

Comment: you need to add connection strings before,and keep them empty.

Comment: you can see on the picture assigned are prerequisites.